# Overpass error: open64

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, overpass-api

Whenever I run any query using the OSM plugin via QGIS, I get the following error:

Overpass error: open64: 2 No such file or directory /srv/overpass/db/area_tags_local.bin File_Blocks::File_Blocks::1

Any suggestions?

I have tried reinstalling the plugin and redownloading QGIS to no avail.